# Angular Shared Modules

Tags: angular

I have researched but still don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have two modules:

- SharedModule
- MainModule

SharedModule contains two Components I care about (for the purpose of this question):

- components\HeaderComponent  (selector: 'my-header')
- components\FooterComponent  (selector: 'my-footer')

Main Module contains one component I care about:

- components\MyHome (selector: 'my-home')

Here's my shared-module.ts:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
  ],

})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And here's my main.component.ts:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyHomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

The application DOES have an `app-routing.module.ts` file but it is not configured.

The error message is as follows:

```
Error: src/app/main/components/my-home/my-home.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'my-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'my-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1 <my-header></my-header>
```

Did I just make a stupid mistake somewhere?

Comment: Try stopping your `ng serve`, delete the `.angular` folder at the root of your project, then run `ng serve` again.

Comment: @MGX didn't work.

Comment: Could you then provide a [mcve] please ?

Comment: Double check the selector then the import statements would be my guess, otherwise the setup looks good

Comment: MainModule is imported in AppModule?

Comment: @CarlesRamos looks like that was it. I was so busy making sure everything was exported from Shared and imported into Main, I didn't check app module.